# Java on Mac. Xcode or other IDE

Tags: java, xcode

I have a question to ask:

I am using a mac and i need to learn how to code java on it.
I have xcode but i'm not sure if all the java components are working properly.

I tried to run a simple program but doesn't seem to work.
when i tried compiling it on my terminal this is the message it gave me:

```
HelloWorld.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.printIn("Hi");
                      ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

Comment: other IDE for sure, intelliJ, eclipse

Comment: It's `println`, not `printIn`.

Comment: what IDE would you suggest? is intelliJ the best one?

Comment: Its just the method that you are calling, read up on some more java. In terms of IDE, I and many others at Google prefer Eclipse. It has really good code-completions functions and little features that are very convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change method name from `printIn` to `println`